# declarative composition vs imperative in react js

Tags: reactjs, frontend

While designing the application in react js to increase the reusability I have used the Tabs and then passed the tabs and headers something like this

```
const tabs ={
   "tabHeader1": TabContent1,
   "tabHeader2": TabContent2

 }
<SwipableTabs tabs={tabs} />
```

Now my confusion arose when I had to render them permission based , In order to avoid if else juggling I have designed a component like below :

```
<ProtectedAction>
{children}
</ProtectedAction>
```

my ProtectedAction component will check for permission and will render the children based on that. Which is exactly what react suggest(be declarative).

Now when I see the above example like tabs which is data driven I am forced to use if else again which I wanted to get rid of.
Please suggest if any better approach is possible .